# Apostrophe CMS : Add fields to piece based on page settings

Tags: apostrophe-cms

Is there a way to add certain fields to a piece based on the current page settings? For eg, if I have a form piece which has 4 input fields is there a way to add an additional 5th field or override the values of the 4 input fields based on the current page settings?

Answer (score -2):

```
we'll write the code for our module in
```

> lib/modules/link-widgets/index.js

```
module.exports = {
  extend: 'apostrophe-widgets',
  label: 'Link to Anywhere',
  addFields: [
    {
      name: 'url',
      type: 'url',
      label: 'URL',
      required: true
    },
    {
      name: 'label',
      type: 'string',
      label: 'Label',
      required: true
    }
  ]
};
```

**Arranging fields**

As we create increasingly complex schemas for pieces and widgets, we will want to arrange the fields in the modal in a way that supports a logical workflow for editors.

We can use arrangeFields to break the schema into multiple tabs in the editor modal. This can be achieved by passing an array of objects, each containing a name, label, and array of fields, to  arrangeFields

```
arrangeFields: [
    {
      name: 'contact',
      label: 'Contact',
      fields: [ 'firstName', 'lastName', 'phone' ]
    },
    {
      name: 'admin',
      label: 'Administrative',
      fields: [ 'slug', 'published', 'tags' ]
    },
    {
      name: 'content',
      label: 'Biographical',
      fields: [ 'thumbnail', 'body' ]
    }
  ],
```

**Adding a field to all pieces**

As explained in the tutorials, the apostrophe-pieces module is a great way to create reusable content that appears all over the site — both on apostrophe-pieces-pages and in apostrophe-pieces-widgets.

We've seen how we can add fields to these by using the addFields option when configuring each module. But sometimes we want to add a field to every type of piece. We can do that by configuring the apostrophe-pieces module itself.

Any configuration we set for apostrophe-pieces becomes part of the configuration for all of the modules that extend it.

Our first idea might be to do this in app.js

/

```
/ lib/modules/apostrophe-pieces/index.js in your project

module.exports = {

  beforeConstruct: function(self, options) {
    options.addFields = [
      {
        type: 'string',
        name: 'author',
        label: 'Author'
      }
    ].concat(options.addFields || [])
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer does not address the question, which is specific to modifying the available fields of a piece based on the fields of the current page.

Comment: I have give answer of this sentences " For eg, if I have a form piece which has 4 input fields is there a way to add an additional 5th field".

Comment: Thanks for your input Maulik.  I'm still unclear about the solution that you suggested. Is there a way to overwrite piece fields and create dynamic fields? @boutell

Comment: @Maulikpatel: "is there a way to add an additional 5th field or override the values of the 4 input fields *based on the current page settings.*" That's why it isn't just a matter of explaining how to add fields normally.

Comment: @bharath please give a more specific example of exactly what you want to see happen. Give an example scenario with a page setting and also clarify the relationship between the page and the pieces. I assume you intentionally are talking about them as separate but related things.

Comment: I mean, is there a way to modify the schema of the widget based on the options that I pass when I instantiate the widget in my template? @boutell.

For eg, if I have a widget with two fields defined in my schema (name, email), and I use this widget it multiple templates. Suppose that I want to include phone_no in a specific template, could I use the same widget for it?

Comment: You would use a separate widget for that purpose since the fields are not the same.

(Note that widgets and pieces are not the same thing. I assume that between your original question and now you have figured out that widgets are a better match for what you are trying to achieve, but I still don't have a complete picture of your problem.)

Comment: Yeah I figured out that using a seperate widget would be the easiest way out of this. But when we call a widget from our template is there a way to access the widget options in the schema and show certain fields just like how we access the options using data.options in our widget.html ? @boutell

Comment: I'm not trying to be difficult but I think I still need more specifics (: Are you sure you're talking about the options you passed *to that widget* in the schema? The schema of... a piece? I gotta see it. Thanks.

Comment: Can I email you as it would be better if I explain my schema with screenshots and stuff? @boutell

Comment: Well... that sounds more like enterprise support (: I think you should try to boil it down to a simple example if you'd like to pursue it via Stack Overflow. Or, we can by all means pursue it as an enterprise support project (see the apostrophecms.org site).